# How to deal with random numbers or letters in file names in R?

Tags: r

I have several files in a directory. he names of the files contain a date that i want extract and use. all files have the same name but only the date change`dat_%Y%m%d_sed`:
 list the files:

```
dir1<- list.files("/data/dat0082009", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
```

extract the date:

```
  date <-   as.POSIXct(strptime(basename(dir1), "dat_%Y%m%d_sed", tz = 
    "GMT"))
  output for example:2008-05-10
```

this works fine but I have other files in another directory where there is a part in the name which change randomly from one file to another
example `dat_1254T_%Y%m%d_sed` another file is `dat_1172T_%Y%m%d_sed`

Normally in Linux we use * for this part but I tried this in R as:
`dat_*_%Y%m%d_sed`

```
date <-   as.POSIXct(strptime(basename(dir1), "dat_*_%Y%m%d_sed", tz = "GMT"))
output: NA
```

it gave NA so it didn't work

any suggestions pls

Comment: You can try a call to `gsub` first : `as.POSIXct(strptime(gsub("dat_(\\d{4}.)_","",basename(dir1)), "%Y%m%d_sed", tz = "GMT"))`

Comment: this is weird, because with "dat_1254T_20080506_sed" I get "2008-05-06 GMT"...

Comment: Actually, I think you've already got your solution: `as.POSIXct(strptime(gsub('.*_(\\d{8}).*','\\1',basename(dir1)), "%Y%m%d", tz = "GMT"))` should give you the right date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably comes from the fact that shell wildcards are different than regular expression special character. The wildcard `*` matches `any string`, while the regexp charachter `*` must be used with some expression before it and means `(the expression) 0 or more times`.

So your regexp should be `"dat_\\d*_%Y%m%d_sed` (`\\d` stands for digit, if you can have letters use `(\\d|\\w)` instead).

The wildcard works in `list.files` because it calls the shell functions with those parameters, but not in `strptime` which is an R function.

**Edit** In fact `strptime` does not accept regexp, solution by CathG :

`as.POSIXct(strptime(gsub('.*_(\\d{8}).*','\\1',basename(dir1)), "%Y%m%d", tz = "GMT"))`

Explanations : `gsub` to extract the date `(\\d{8})` from the string and `strptime` to process it.

Comment: yep, appears `strptime` does not accept regexp, you need gsub.

Comment: @Math, you're welcome ;-) and BTW, the solution is not really mine but rather OP's...

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the date using regular expressions:

```
fn <- "dat_1172T_150201_sed"
pat <- "_[^_]+_sed$"
m <- gregexpr(pat, fn)
new_fn <- regmatches(fn,m)[[1]]
```

Now you can apply `strptime` on `new_fn`.